# Отправка логов на email в Android

Tags: android, c#, android-sdk, логирование, xamarin

Добрый день! Пишу приложение под Android с помощью Xamarin.Android. Так как в приложении могут случаться ошибки, то хотелось бы быть в курсе, что это за ошибки, когда и как они происходили и тд. Я хотел бы при их возникновении отправлять информацию о них на email. Скажем, если использовать библиотеку log4net то эта задача выглядит очень просто. Но к сожалению Xamarin приложения не поддерживают использование этой библиотеки. Может кто-то знает как вообще решить эту задачу без написания своих велосипедов для логирования? Как это вообще реализуют в Android приложениях? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: для native Android есть море библиотек, например ACRA. Xamarin сам по себе изврещенный и недоделанный, говорю не понаслышке, сейчас поддерживаю проект на нем

Comment: к сожалению переходить из-за одного только логирования на native я не могу. Проще уж самому написать тогда

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант написать самому с помощью System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(в сборке с System.dll). Если есть сеть сразу отправлять, а если отсутствует сохранять и отправлять когда появится. Конечно это не очень вариант, потому что придется вручную отлавливать ошибки.

```
try
{
  //Ваш код
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  //Метод отправки или сохранения логов
}
```